# Add a "Select All" check box (expand : true) along with TreeView data in Kendo UI with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, treeview, kendo-treeview

I am working on kendo UI Tree view. Here I have to add a "Select All" check box with [expandable : true].

In my Code, I have used a template. Below I am linking my Dojo Link.

Please check and give solution if possible.
http://dojo.telerik.com/EKaFu/3

[image: Image - This is what I want]

Here is another example.
[image]